# What exactly does Vagrant snapshot save?

Tags: vagrant, snapshot, vagrant-plugin

I use Vagrant on VirtualBox. Yesterday, I saved a snapshot of my project by running:

```
$ vagrant snapshot save 'my-project-date-time'
```

Today, I've made some changes to files and folders in my project that I want to revert. When I run:

```
$ vagrant snapshot restore 'my-project-date-time'
```

... the restoring process is completed successfully, yet the changed files and folders in my project remain the same and do not revert to the sate they were when the snapshot was taken yesterday.

So what exactly does the Vagrant snapshot save?

Comment: It depends on the provider. 

AWS: snapshot = ebs snapshot
ovirt: native libvirt disk snapshot

etc

Comment: sorry, but what???

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Vagrant snapshots just call the provider "snapshots" method. So Vagrant snapshot on virtualbox just calls virtualbox snapshot.

> So what exactly does the Vagrant snapshot save?

More info on virtualbox snapshots can be found here: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#snapshots

Comment: is there a way I can include project folder into a snapshot?

Comment: If the provider doesn't support it, then no. And i'm 99% sure you can't do that with the functionality. you could sync the folder into VBOX and use cp to put it on the FS then snapshot however